# Saving a char array to the iPhone

Tags: objective-c, c, ios, arrays, char

I have an unsigned char array in c that I need to store on the iPhone and load this back up when required.
The simplest way to explain the contents of the char array is simply a hex or similar representation of how may times a button has been pressed. (Though it's a lot more complicated than that)

```
unsigned char myCounter[28];
```

I just want to know what the best way is to store this on the iPhone and load it back into a global variable. I have tried converting to an NSString and back again. Though this works, I'm unsure how to store this into a global variable (available to all my c functions).

Sorry, I'm totally new to C programming.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If it's just arbitrary bytes, NSData is the best OO-ish way to represent arbitrary byte arrays like this.

```
NSData *counterAsObject = [NSData dataWithBytes:myCounter length:28];
// and then you can…
[counterAsObject writeToFile:whereverYouWantToStoreIt atomically:YES];
```

You can also store NSData in property lists if this is part of some larger configuration that you want to store all together.

If it's meant to be text, you can simply make an NSString out of it (you'll probably want to do this to interact with the rest of Cocoa Touch anyway).

Answer (score 0):

If you have it as an NSString, you can call:

```
[myString writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&myErr];
```

You'll need to create filePath. It should probably point to your app's document directory, or Application Support directory.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use NSArray?  Much more pleasant to work with than plain C arrays, especially if you are "totally new to C programming."

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to save an `NSString` for use later is via `NSUserDefaults`.

```
NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// set
[userDefaults setValue:CHAR_ARRAY_CONVERTED_TO_NSSTRING forKey:@"MyKey"];

// get
NSString * savedString = [userDefaults valueForKey:@"MyKey"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you would like to store it on the file system or within your running application (or both). Storing to file system can be done via the method user1118321 and sho described. If you would like to access it globally, my approach would be to make a class with a shared instance (singleton). The singleton stores the array and all the time you would need to access it by a different classes you just have to reference the singleton and call a method that returns the array.

How to create singletons: [Correct way to alloc shared instance (singleton)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409830/correct-way-to-alloc-shared-instance-singleton)

Class header would look like:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    unsigned char *myCounter;
}
...
@end
```

Within your init method of MyClass you need set the pointer with:

```
...
myCounter = new char[28];
...
```

And to access the counter you can create a getter e.g.:

```
- (char*)getCounter
{
    return myCounter;
}
```

Whenever you would like to have access to the array, import the MyClass header and reference the array by calling:

```
char *array = [[MyClass sharedInstance] getCounter];
```

However, you will not know the number of entries in your array (as it's a C-Array).
I would suggest to define a pre-processor directive like

```
#define kArraySize 28
```

within your class header file and which can be used to alloc the array and to know it's size anywhere else in your code.
If the write/read access to this array is very limited, I suggest you to go with NSArray.